# how to get HttpGet and HttpPost in one event in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to get `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` method in one click event 
Ex: When users click into link, then display a detail page and update status of link into database.
Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to say is you need a link which calls your controller (to store some stuff in some database). And then displays a detail page, right?

You can simply use `@Html.ActionLink` helper method to generate a link to a controller/action for you. The action should be your detail action of whatever controller you need.

Within the controller action implementation, save some stuff to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the database update in your GET action itself before returning the view.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  yourRepositary.MarkMessageAsRead(id);
  var messageVM=yourService.GetMessage(id);
  return View(messageVM);
}
```